# Rate of change of area depending of the circumference of a circle

Tags: geometry, derivatives, euclidean-geometry

I want to find the general formula which gives the rate of change of the area with respect to the circumference. (Of a circle)

I know that I can use differentiation formulas but I don't want to do it that way.

We have : $C=2\pi r$ when we isolate for r it gives : $r=\frac{C}{2\pi}$

and $A=\pi*r^2$

Basically what I did is this :

A=$\frac{(\pi*(r1+r2)^2)-(\pi*r1^2)}{r1+r2-r1}$

I'm supposed to obtain Circumference divided by $2*\pi$

What did I do wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other than the missing limit, the problem is that you are setting up the computation for $\frac{\partial A}{\partial r}(r)$ and you are expecting that substituting $r = \frac{C}{2\pi}$ it will give you $\frac{\partial A}{\partial C}(C)$. This is not possible. Instead, by the chain rule we know that
$$
\frac{\partial A}{\partial C}(C) =  \frac{\partial r}{\partial C}(C) \; \frac{\partial A}{\partial r}(r(C)) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \; \frac{\partial A}{\partial r}\left(\frac{C}{2\pi}\right).
$$

---

To compute $\frac{\partial A}{\partial C}(C)$ directly as a limit, consider $h > 0$. Then
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial A}{\partial C}(C)
&= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\pi \left(\frac{C+h}{2\pi}\right)^2 - \pi \left(\frac{C}{2\pi}\right)^2}{h} \\
&= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{(C+h)^2 - C^2}{4\pi h}\\
&= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{2Ch + h^2}{4\pi h}\\
&= \underbrace{\left(\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{2Ch}{4\pi h}\right)}_{C/2\pi}
+ \underbrace{\left(\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{h^2}{4\pi h}\right)}_0.
\end{align}
$$

---

On the other hand, if you know that $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} x^2 = 2x$ it is way quicker to just observe that
$$
A = \pi r^2 = \frac{1}{4\pi} C^2
$$
immediately implies
$$
\frac{\partial A}{\partial C}(C) = \frac{1}{4 \pi} \; \frac{\partial}{\partial C} C^2 = \frac{1}{2\pi} C.
$$

Comment: Yes I know how to do it that way. But that's not how I want to do it.

Comment: r1=Circumference divided by 2pi and r2=Circumference divided by 2pi

Comment: Then could you please explain how you want to do it? This is by far the quickest and simplest solution...

Comment: What we usually do to calculate a derivative is f(x+h)-f(x) divided by (x+h-x) That's how I want to do it.

Comment: No, what you do is take the *limit* of that for $h \to 0$...

Comment: Yeah, you're right. But that's what I want to do but it's not working. Do you see where I did wrong in what I did ?

Comment: That's probably because you are working with $r$ instead of $C$, thus you are computing $\partial A / \partial r$ instead of $\partial A / \partial C$...

Comment: Well, we can always replace the r at the end when we did all the calculations....

Comment: Here's what I obtain : C1 + (C2/2) :/

Comment: I'm going to try this on my own and see :p

Comment: Just a question : why you didn't write the first fraction in this way : C/2π+ h ??? Is this an error from you ?

Comment: Because I'm computing the derivative with respect to $C$, not with respect to $r$... by the chain rule $$\frac{\partial A}{\partial C} =  \frac{\partial r}{\partial C} \; \frac{\partial A}{\partial r} = \frac{1}{2\pi} \; \frac{\partial A}{\partial r}.$$

Comment: Oh ok so it does make a difference then.